# GNUPLOT: Histogram clustered decrease inter-histogram space to increase box widths

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to decrease the spaces marked by red boxes in the below plot (i.e., inter histogram space) so that the bar widths increase?

[image]

My plot script has following options:

```
set terminal pdfcairo font "Latin-Modern-Roman-Bold,20" size 5,3
set style histogram clustered gap 1

plot \
  newhistogram "", 'mydata.tsv' using 3:xtic(1) t col ls 11, '' u 4 t col ls 6, '' u 5 t col ls 12, '' u 6 t col ls 14, '' u 7 t col ls 4, \
  newhistogram "", '' using 9:xtic(1) t col ls 11, '' u 10 t col ls 6, '' u 11 t col ls 12, '' u 12 t col ls 14, '' u 13 t col ls 4, \
  newhistogram "", '' using 15:xtic(1) t col ls 11, '' u 16 t col ls 6, '' u 17 t col ls 12, '' u 18 t col ls 14, '' u 19 t col ls 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The `newhistogram` allows you to provide a starting position along x.

```
plot \
  newhistogram "" at 0, ...
  newhistogram "" at 10., ...
```